# Passing forward Core Data Stack?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to learn Core Data and I'm pretty confused. The first tutorial I was following, from (London App Brewery) was using class cogen and accessing the context with:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

However I recently bought and read core-data-by-tutorials by raywenderlich, and they set it up using manual/none. And created their own coreData Stack:

import Foundation
import CoreData

```
class CoreDataStack {

  private let modelName: String

  init(modelName: String) {
    self.modelName = modelName
  }

  lazy var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    return self.storeContainer.viewContext
  }()

  private lazy var storeContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: self.modelName)
    container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
      if let error = error as NSError? {
        print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      }
    }
    return container
  }()

  func saveContext () {
    guard managedContext.hasChanges else { return }

    do {
      try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
  }
}
```

And then accessed it on the viewController using:

```
lazy var coreDataStack = CoreDataStack(modelName: "Potfolio")
```

But the tutorials are pretty simple and they don't mention passing the stack along. I just had an issue with data not saving, and after some digging in the tutorial code, I fond this in the app delegate:

```
guard let tabController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController,
      let employeeListNavigationController = tabController.viewControllers?[0] as? UINavigationController,
      let employeeListViewController = employeeListNavigationController.topViewController as? EmployeeListViewController else {
        fatalError("Application storyboard mis-configuration. Application is mis-configured")
    }

    employeeListViewController.coreDataStack = coreDataStack
```

Which lead me to use the prepare:for() when using a segue to pass the stack forward. Which then did save the data I was trying to save.

**So my question is:** I cant imagine passing the core data stack along with the segue is the correct way to go about things? And if it isn't, whats the correct way to pass the stack forward?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the stack instance along via segues, but as you point out that doesn't *feel* right, and is prone to error. One way to accomplish this is to add a **static** instance to your `CoreDataStack` class.

```swift
class CoreDataStack {
  
  static let portfolio: CoreDataStack = {
    return CoreDataStack(modelName: "Portfolio")
  }()

  ...
}
```

This takes the place of your *lazy var* instantiated in your view controller. In its place you can add:

```swift
class EmployeeListViewController: UIViewController {

  let coreDataData = CoreDataStack.portfolio

  ...

}
```

In this example you create a single instance (singleton) that can be accessed from anywhere in your apps code.